# How to copy combobox so cell link changes automatically

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, hyperlink, copy-paste

Is it possible to copy a created combobox and paste it in another cell so
that cell link is changed too?

I do this work with Excel 2007.

Example: I have combobox in A5, cell link pointing to B5. I want to copy
the combo box to cell A4 and the cell link to point to B4.

I need to copy more than 50 comboboxes. I tried to use it when I push the commandbutton which include the macro to copy a entire row and insert all of it to the new row.

I found one answer but VBA showed "Compile error: User defined type not defined!" and "TypeOf cbo.Object Is msforms.ComboBox" is bold.

Macro I found:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim cbo As OLEObject

    For Each cbo In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeOf cbo.Object Is msforms.ComboBox Then
            cbo.LinkedCell = cbo.TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1).Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The original answer put me on the right track and works for the "ActiveX control".  I needed to do the same thing with a standard Excel "Form control" combobox and it's pretty similar, except it's a shape object and it needs to be selected to be manipulated.  Here's my code, which worked for me:

```
Sub AllocateLinkedCellsToComobBoxes()

Dim myShape As Shape

For Each myShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If myShape.Type = msoFormControl Then
        If myShape.FormControlType = xlDropDown Then
            myShape.Select
            Selection.LinkedCell = Selection.TopLeftCell.Address
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Reima,

If you are using controls from the "Control Toolbox" toolbar, then the following should work.  The only difference is that it's not an MSForms.Combobox.  :

```
Sub Test()
Dim cbo As OLEObject

For Each cbo In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeOf cbo.Object Is ComboBox Then
        cbo.LinkedCell = cbo.TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1).Address
    End If
Next    
End Sub
```

If you are using a combobox from the "Forms" toolbar, then I'm not sure what the best approach is.  I'd try using the method above.